# Why Go channel is blocking but not quitting

Tags: go, channel

I have those two versions to implement context cancellation over signals using [signal.NotifyContext](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext)

Version 1 https://play.golang.org/p/rwOnYEgPecE

```
func main() {
    ch := run()
    <-ch
}

func run() chan bool {
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    var done = make(chan bool)

    //go func() {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Quitting")
        stop()
        done <- true
    }
    //}()
    return done
}
```

Version 2 https://play.golang.org/p/oijbICeSrNT

```
func main() {
    ch := run()
    <-ch
}

func run() chan bool {
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    var done = make(chan bool)

    go func() {
       select {
       case <-ctx.Done():
          fmt.Println("Quitting")
          stop()
          done <- true
       }
    }()
    return done
}
```

Why is the first version printing the line `Quitting` but does not exit, while the second version prints and quits properly?

Comment: on the playgrond they both cancel and exit. What is your OS, go version, go env ?

Comment: @mh-cbon  to avoid excessive CPU usage of the platform, the playground has a built-in max time-limit for execution, so will kill programs automatically if they run too long.

Comment: @colm.anseo yes, maybe, but in both case the pass through the `<-context.Done()` case, thus, theey both cancel before quitting.

Comment: The problem in the first case is that the `done` channel is unbuffered

Comment: but anyway, just close it, it will do https://play.golang.org/p/hY7RmVVTfOu

Comment: In reality, a signal handler only makes sense if it's run in its own goroutine.

Comment: I am running on Windows 10. go 16.2 and go env is GOPATH = ~\go and GO111MODULE=auto

Comment: Thank you @mh-cbon. That is a new insight into channels. Can you please explain how it worked with goroutine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the first case doesn't behave as you expect is because everything is running in a single (main) goroutine.

```
select {
   case <-ctx.Done():
      fmt.Println("Quitting")
      stop()
      done <- true  // this blocks because no one is listening
   }
}
```

in your second example because the above logic is run in a goroutine, then `main()` will be listening on the channel.

The second method is preferred, since any signal handler - which is running for the lifetime of a program - should be running in its own goroutine.

Comment: the code comment really is the key reason here.

Comment: first code : go routine x blocks writing in the channel, nobody to read. second : go routine x blocks, go routine y read, x unblocks, x exit, y exit.

Comment: @colm.anseo I accepted as answer. Thanks UmNyobe.  But how did closing channel helped with first version?

Comment: Closing a channel is a non-blocking operation. It is commonly used as a mechanism to signal something is "done" - as any read operations will unblock.